# How to setup a Freedos with old Kernel version (2026a) to system

Tags: boot, operating-systems, formatting, bootable-media, freedos

I bought a laptop with Freedos 1.1.26a build (2026a) and I formatted it to Windows 10. Now I want to get it back to Freedos with same version before.

A solution on web was saying that formating where Windows 10 is installed and rebooting system will bring me to FreeDos again automatically so I formatted C: and reboot my system but it brought me to Windows Boot Error (A screen with "Recovery" title).

When I try to create a bootable Freedos CD or USB, all solutions are about new versions of FreeDos so they want an image or iso file.

I found system files from there: [Freedos Kernel Files 2026a](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freedos/files/Kernel/2.0.26.a/) but I don't know how I can use them or how I can create a bootable media to install this version of OS to my pc again. There is no ISO or IMG files from there.

This is my FreeDos screen before I installed Windows.

[image]

Can you please help?

Thank you.

Comment: This begs the question, “what are you really trying to do?” Obviously a laptop with FreeDos on it is virtually unusable, so are you trying to return the laptop? Resell the laptop? What? Maybe there is a misunderstanding there.

Comment: Is there something special about that FreeDOS version? Won't the current release work just as well?

Comment: The web shop where i bought this laptop accepted my return product request by i want to return it as how i bought it so yes. FreeDos version is important for me.